# R Plotly how do I clear selection?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have a plotly plot that looks something like this:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

irisd <- iris %>% highlight_key(~Species)
g <- ggplot(irisd, aes(x = Petal.Width, y=Sepal.Width, color = Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_bw() + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20)) + 
  scale_color_viridis_c()

ggplotly(g, tooltip = "groups")
```

This is great in that it allows me to select entire groups by clicking on any point.

However, I'd like to be able to clear the selection without reloading the webpage. How?

Answer (score 0):

Just double click somewhere in the plot where there is no data point.

Comment: This is the way a reset the selection. I am sorry it is not working for you.